# writing header to ls output files

Tags: linux, shell

I am using below `gsutil` command to download the list of empty files. I would like to write header as `"filename"` before output gets written.

```
gsutil ls -l "gs://test-data-prod-ingest/cm_data/AN/CM/*/a01_*_20210128*.csv.bz2" | awk '{if ($1 <= 100) print $3}' > ls_output.csv
```

output should be like that

```
filename
somefile1
somefile2
---
---
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try:

```
...| awk '!hdr{ print "something as header"; hdr=1; }; $1 <= 100{ print $3; }'
```

this has an advantage of to having printing header line only if there is something read by awk from its stdin, while if we write a header line within `BEGIN{...}` block, that will print the header line even when no data is read from the input.

or even better to print header only when at least there is one record with the matched condition to print:

```
...| awk '$1<=100 { if (!hdr) { print "something as header"; hdr=1; }; print $3; } '
```

Comment: Could also use the condition `NR == 1` with the same effect.

Comment: @glennjackman ah, yes, that is also another option.

Comment: Perfect ! Will it print no header in case there is nothing to write?

Comment: Could you please also suggest to fix the issue when file name is having spaces in between.. how to search in that case.. for example file name is "510154_Call Dropping Measurement_04Feb2021_1100-04Feb2021_1200.csv.bz2"

Comment: filename with no spaces "a01_1h_255_ISZSH1_202101220100_0009.csv.bz2"

Comment: and here is file name with spaces "510154_Call Dropping Measurement_04Feb2021_1100-04Feb2021_1200.csv.bz2"

Comment: enclose your file names between single quotes like `'file name with spaces'`

Comment: How like one below? gsutil ls -l 'gs://test-bucket/cm_data/ABC/PM/*/510154_Call Dropping Measurement_04Feb2021_*.csv.bz2' | awk '{if ($1 >= 100) print $3 }'

Comment: yes, exactly like that

Comment: same problem.. it prints filename till it found first space

Comment: what does this commad returns `gsutil ls -l 'gs://test-bucket/cm_data/ABC/PM/*/510154_Call Dropping Measurement_04Feb2021_*.csv.bz2'`?

Comment: gs://test-bucket/cm_data/ABC/PM/10.40.146.194-CORE-PM-6/510154_Call

Comment: hmm, that's the question about `gsutil ls -l` then which I don't know how it works except that I could only say quoting may resolve the issue while it didn't. I suggest you to open a new question for that.